# MVC return file and clear model state

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have single button on one page which call method to return file, when there is any problem then I add error to model state when is not, then I clear it.

The problem is that when I return only the file, then if previously there was some error added to model state, now after downloading file, model state is not refreshing and I can still see the error.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file, HomeViewModel model, string command)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reportPath) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reportName))
    {          
        ModelState.Clear();
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, reportName);
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "File wrong format");

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your Action returns the File, it does not response with a new view, rendered with your viewModel. Nor will the ModelState be rendered within your view. You can verify this, with a dev-toolbar(eg. Firebug) and see the request/response when you push the button. The HTML-Page won't be transmitted, in case your Actions returns the file.

In your case, simply remove the warnings from your client with JavaScript when you push the button. If the download is successful, you won't see the errors no longer. If your Action returns with a Error (and ModelState) it will be rendered again and display the error